# How to make publishable tables and plots using R?

Tags: r, latex, xtable, publish-actions

Suppose I want a table that looks something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265764/a-booktabs-question-how-to-get-rid-of-the-blank-column

And I have all the numbers from R results. What I can do now is use booktabs in latex to make this table, but I have to entry the numbers manually by copy and paste.

The latex code I used is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}\centering
\ra{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rrrrcrrrcrrr@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} & 
\phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 16$} &
\phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}\\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8} \cmidrule{10-12}
& $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$\\\midrule
$dir=1$\\
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 && 0.3670 & 0.7187 & 3.1815 && -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384&& -9.0714& 297.0923& 46.2143&& 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721&& 128.2265& -630.5455& -381.0930&& -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
$dir=0$\\
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119&& 0.3593& -0.2755& 2.1764&& -1.2998& -3.8202& -1.2784\\
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591&& -30.7381& -9.5952& -3.0000&& -11.1631& -5.7108& -15.6728\\
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351&& 100.2497& 141.2778& -259.7326&& 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to generate this kind of table without entry numbers manually?

Can I use Sweave or xtable in latex do this? Which way is easier? (Though they both seem to be very complicated for me).

I also thought about exporting R result into SAS to make publishable tables, but I doubt whether it would work.

Comment: Maybe take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660359/general-guide-for-creating-publication-quality-tables-using-r-sweave-and-latex I really couldn't recommend SAS ODF unless you want to shorten your life through pure frustration.

Comment: @ thelatemail  haha, I did try SAS proc report earlier, it was really frustrating ! And thanks, I'll check it out!