# Table format of ANOVA output

Tags: r, format, tabular, anova

I have a large dataset on which I am performing ANOVA analysis. I'm not sure how to get the output of the analysis into a table that I can use in a Word document (without retyping all of the values manually).

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
var1 <- c("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", "Red","Red", "Green", "Blue",    "Blue", "Red",
      "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Blue", "Red","Red", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", "Red")
var2 <- c(10, 20, 15, 32, 10, 20, 15, 32, 10, 20, 15, 32, 10, 20, 15, 32, 10, 20, 15, 32)

df <- data.frame(var1, var2)

TukeyHSD(aov(var2 ~ var1))
```

This produces an output that looks like this:

```
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = var2 ~ var1)

$var1
            diff        lwr       upr     p adj 
Green-Blue -8.25 -21.183389  4.683389 0.2580147 
Red-Blue   -2.75 -13.310068  7.810068 0.7848043 
Red-Green   5.50  -7.433389 18.433389 0.5323260
```

I would like the output to be in a format that is easy to cut and paste into Word that includes the headings, "Variable", "Difference" and "p value". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Save output `output <- TukeyHSD(aov(var2 ~ var1))` and `output$var1` will contain a matrix with your values. You can convert to data frame with `as.data.frame(output$var1)`

Comment: Thanks @ChiPak . That solution does help but I still don't have a table that is "publication ready" (if that makes sense). I can't just cut and paste the output into Word without it looking a little messy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [General guide for creating publication quality tables using R, Sweave, and LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660359/general-guide-for-creating-publication-quality-tables-using-r-sweave-and-latex)

Comment: `write.tsv(as.data.frame(output$var1), "C:\folder", header=T)` and open with Excel.

Comment: thanks @ChiPak - I get an error saying "could not find function "write.tsv"" (is there a package that I need to install to access that function?)

Comment: Sorry, I normally use `readr` which has `write_tsv`. I think you have to use `write.csv(as.data.frame(output$var1), "C:\folder", header=T, sep="\t")` or you can not specify `sep` for a comma-delimited file.